# Coding a coordinate system rotation

Tags: coordinate-systems, geodesy

I am trying to calculate the azimuth, elevation and range of a point above the Earth's surface.

[A handy wikipedia picture to clarify the azer coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtngl.png)

The latter two are simple, but I am having trouble finding the azimuth. Currently I am looking into rotating the coordinate system, so that the OX axis points North and the XY plane is parallel to the plane tangetial to Earth's ellipsoid in the observation point. In the transfromed coordinate system the azimuth should be as simple as
$atan2(r_y,r_x)$, where the vector $\mathbf r$ is the vector pointing from the observation point to the object above Earth's surface.

I have written a simple program to try and do the transformation. The first transformation rotates the system around the OZ axis, resulting in OX pointing north, the second rotates the system around the OY axis, resulting in OZ pointing along the normal to the ellipsoid's tangential plane. n is the normal vector.

```
    cos_rot_z = -ntx/np.sqrt(ntx*ntx+nty*nty)
    sin_rot_z = np.sqrt(1. - cos_rot_z*cos_rot_z) 

    rtx = rtx*cos_rot_z - rty*sin_rot_z
    rty = rtx*sin_rot_z + rty*cos_rot_z
    rtz = rtz

    ntx = ntx*cos_rot_z - nty*sin_rot_z
    nty = ntx*sin_rot_z + nty*cos_rot_z
    ntz = ntz

    ntmod = np.sqrt(ntx*ntx+nty*nty+ntz*ntz)
    rtmod = np.sqrt(rtx*rtx+rty*rty+rtz*rtz)
    print("Transformation 1\nntmod, rtmod",ntmod,rtmod)

    cos_rot_y = ntz/nmod
    sin_rot_y = np.sqrt(1. - cos_rot_y*cos_rot_y)

    rtx = rx*cos_rot_y + rz*sin_rot_y
    rty = ry
    rtz = -rx*sin_rot_y + rz*cos_rot_y

    ntx = nx*cos_rot_y + nz*sin_rot_y
    nty = ny
    ntz = -nx*sin_rot_y + nz*cos_rot_y

    ntmod = np.sqrt(ntx*ntx+nty*nty+ntz*ntz)
    rtmod = np.sqrt(rtx*rtx+rty*rty+rtz*rtz)
    print("Transformation 2\nntmod, rtmod",ntmod,rtmod)
```

However, in the output the moduli of the vectors change after the first transfromation:

```
    nmod, rmod [1.56801421e-07] [6096634.62776758]
    Transformation 1
    ntmod, rtmod [1.46743607e-07] [6096426.73822206]
    Transformation 2
    ntmod, rtmod [1.56801421e-07] [6096634.62776758]
```

I am lost as to why this happens. Could it help, if, instead of multiplying the rotation matrices with the vectors I multiplied the matrices with each other and then multiplied the product with the vectors?

Comment: I didn't check the code in detail, but my guess is that it's a numerical error. Try to compute the determinant of the first matrix. It should be equal to
$$
\sin^2{} + \cos^2{} = 1
$$
where sin and cos are the respective terms. It's not unusual that there are some small errors in computing sine and cosine ...

Comment: Done!
T1 matrix determinant: [1.]

T2 matrix determinant: [1.]

This is, however, just a symptom of my using the very same formula to calculate the sine.

Comment: This determinant computation isn’t a very useful diagnostic because you never construct or use matrices explicitly. There is, however, an error in the way that you’ve hand-coded these transformations.

Comment: There’s a fundamental programming error that occurs over and over in this code: it updates dependent sets of values sequentially instead of in parallel. For instance, the three lines of code in the second “paragraph” are trying to update `rtx`, `rty` and `rtz` by rotating this point about the $z$-axis. However, the value of `rtx` is updated first and then this new, rotated `rtx` is used instead of the correct original value to compute `rty`. This can lead to all kinds of mysterious problems. You need to save the new values to temps or use copies of the original values to compute the rotation.

Comment: My god, you're right! That must be it! Thank you very much!